# Mathematical induction final step -- proving $n^3 \leq 2^n$, where $n\geq 10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I was solving an induction exercise, but I got stuck here, and I'd like a hint ($n \geq 10$).

**Claim:** $n^3 \leq 2^n$

I have that $3n^2 + 3n \leq 2^n - 1$, but I am unsure as to how to proceed.

Comment: Your question was not the clearest in that it is not very clear whether or not you meant to prove $3n^2 + 3n \leq 2^n - 1$ or $n^3\leq 2^n$ for $n\geq 10$. In any case, my answer addresses the first inequality and JMoravitz addresses the second inequality.

Comment: I meant to prove the second one - thanks for answer crush anyway, will look at it too

Comment: @II I just modified your question to reflect what you wanted more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your question is specifically how to prove:

> $n^3\leq 2^n$ holds for $n\geq 10$

Proof: For $n=10$, you have $n^3=10^3=1000<1024=2^{10}=2^n$.

Suppose for our induction hypothesis that it is true that $n^3\leq 2^n$ for some $n\geq 10$.  We want to show that it follows for $n+1$ as well.

$$(n+1)^3=n^3+3n^2+3n+1 \leq^{I.H.} 2^n + 3n^2+3n+1\\
\leq 2^n + 3n^2+3n^2+6n^2\leq 2^n+10n^2\leq 2^n+n^3\leq^{I.H.}2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}$$

I made the jump from the end of the top line to the beginning of the bottom line by simply noting that for $n\geq 1$ that I am adding extra and multiplying by extra positive numbers greater than 1, thereby increasing the total.  Also, noting that $n\geq 10$ tells me that $10n^2\leq n^3$.

Therefore $(n^3\leq 2^n)\wedge (n\geq 10)\Rightarrow (n+1)^3\leq 2^{n+1}$, so the claim is true for all $n\geq 10$.

Comment: Interesting. I took the claim to be $3n^2 + 3n \leq 2^n - 1$. Well, at least the OP has *two* answers now to address either question. Question wasn't the clearest.

Comment: Indeed.  The one claim should likely follow from the other though in any case.

Comment: Right. I commented on OP's question so he can see how both inequalities would be done, regardless. I would upvote, but I am out of votes right now. Upvote you in 2 hours :)

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** The following proves the inequality $3n^2 + 3n \leq 2^n - 1$ for $n\geq 10$. This appeared to be a possible interpretation of the OP's original question. Regardless, both inequalities are now addressed.

Here's the meat of the argument:
\begin{align}
2^{k+1}-1 &= 2\cdot 2^{k}-1\tag{definition}\\[0.5em]
        &= 2(2^k-1)+1\tag{manipulate}\\[0.5em]
        &\geq 2(3k^2+3k)+1\tag{induction hypothesis}\\[0.5em]
        &= 6k^2+6k+1\tag{expand}\\[0.5em]
        &\geq 3k^2+9k+6\tag{since $k\geq 10$}\\[0.5em]
        &=3(k+1)^2+3(k+1).\tag{desired expression}
\end{align}